# Position labels to different sides in the parent pane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a question about positioning Text into Bar area.

I created this example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();

        flow.setPrefSize(900, 30);

        Label label = new Label("Zoom 1.5");
        Label labelStat = new Label("Users 7");
        Label labelSec = new Label("Connected");

        flow.getChildren().addAll(label, labelStat, labelSec);

        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().add(flow);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hb);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

How I can get this visual result:

[image]

In my case I want to resize the main stage and preserve the relative position of the Text. I can change FlowPane with different Layout if there is more suitable component.

Answer (score 4):

You may choose to use `StackPane` and align its children differently:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{

    StackPane flow = new StackPane();

    flow.setPrefSize(900, 30);

    Label label = new Label("Zoom 1.5");
    Label labelStat = new Label("Users 7");
    Label labelSec = new Label("Connected");

    StackPane.setAlignment( label, Pos.CENTER_LEFT );
    StackPane.setAlignment( labelStat, Pos.CENTER );
    StackPane.setAlignment( labelSec, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT );

    flow.getChildren().addAll(label, labelStat, labelSec);

    Scene scene = new Scene(flow);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you foresee adding more labels in the future, would be to utilize a spacer (or spring) implementation in an `HBox`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.setPrefSize(900, 30);

    Label label = new Label("Zoom 1.5");
    Label labelStat = new Label("Users 7");
    Label labelSec = new Label("Connected");

    Region lSpring = new Region();
    HBox.setHgrow(lSpring, Priority.ALWAYS);
    Region rSpring = new Region();
    HBox.setHgrow(rSpring, Priority.ALWAYS);

    hbox.getChildren().addAll(label, lSpring, labelStat, rSpring, labelSec);
    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox);

    primaryStage.setTitle("HBox Springs");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```