# ScrollPane inside a StackPane

Tags: text, scroll, javafx, scrollpane

I have the following problem:
I have a ScrollPane inside a StackPane, and I can't scroll.

To be exact:
I have a BorderPane (root of the scene). On the bottom of the borderPane, I use a StackPane. On this Stackpane, there are 3 Nodes (2 Groups and the ScrollPane). The Scrollpane has a TextFlow as content. 
I see the scrollbar, but when I try to scroll, nothing happens. When I replace my StackPane with e.g. a HBox it works. Anyone here who could explain to me why this seems not to work with a StackPane? (And is there a way to make it work with the StackPane?)

```
StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
StackPane.setAlignment(scrollPane, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
stackPane.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
```

Oh, by the way:
I used the StackPane because I want those 3 Nodes to get aligned differently (one on the left side, one centered, one on the right side). If there is another possibility to do that without a StackPane, I'm fine with that too.

Thank you

Edit: 
I changed to a BorderPane instead of a StackPane, using the left, center and right parts to realize the alignment. Now the ScrollPane works and the alignment is also correct. But still, why does it not work with a StackPane?

Comment: Is the scrollpane last node added to stackpane's children list? I.e. is it it on top?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849096/position-labels-to-different-sides-in-the-parent-pane for HBox version alignment.

Comment: @Uluk Biy No, I added the scrollpane first. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, Stackpane will align its children on top of another. So even you align them to different sides, it is "layered" on top of each other. As a result the mouse and key events are arrived to top node only. The last added node will be on top (z-order).

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that! Thank you really much for the explanation.